# How do I change the resolution of Men of War?

Tags: technical-issues, men-of-war

I am trying to manually set the resolution of the game Men of War to 1280x1024 to play a mod.

I have tried to use the *nircmd* to change the resolution but some error message pops up and then the game exits. There are no in-game settings to change the resolution, but I am quite sure it is possible by editing the settings file. However I do not know how to do this.

How is the resolution changed in Men of War

Comment: Are you talking about Men of War or Men of War 2 , Men of War: Vietnam, etc?

Comment: I am talking about Men of War.

Comment: Has your problem been resolved already? Was it by the given answer or not? If not, please add an answer yourself if you've found a way to change the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the settings file can be found at C:\Documents and Settings\Your_User_Name\My Documents\my games\men of war\profiles\username and then find the options.set file. [Source](http://forum.1cpublishing.eu/showthread.php?t=14905).

Note: I do not know how easy it is to edit this file, but having Notepad++ would come in very handy in case it isn't super easy to edit the file.